# Setting up HTTPS in your Environment---Site not Working after SSL settings

Tags: django

I need some help in order to fix my production SSL settings.
I have put these settings and when i enable them the production site doesnt work. I erased them, the site is working only on http. Is this right?
Why this happens on the production site?

```
 CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER      = True
 # HOST_SCHEME                     = "https://, http://"
 HOST_SCHEME                     = "https://"
 SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER         = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
 SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT             = True
 SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE           = True
 CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE              = True
 SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  = True
 SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS             = 1000000
 SECURE_FRAME_DENY               = True
```

I would appreciate if you can help me!

Thanks!

Comment: What web server are you using to host the Django application?

Comment: Greg i use a virtual server from my country. Is no name etc

Comment: I don't mean the physical server, I mean the **web** server. Are you using Apache? Django development server? Also, what do you mean "the site doesn't work". Do you get a red SSL error? Does the site not respond at all on ports 443/80?

Comment: I want to answer this question, but I cannot since the question is not clear. I don't know what your actual problem is because you haven't defined it well enough.

Comment: check pls www.cohen.ro i use django's server

Comment: If you're using Django's server, then HTTPS will require another piece of software. You might want to look here: https://www.isotoma.com/blog/2012/07/17/running-a-django-dev-instance-over-https/

Comment: cool stuff Greg! Thank you! will try!

Comment: Also, I don't think this is a quality question, since it isn't specific enough, but I don't want to discourage you as a new StackOverflow member. I would recommend that you voluntarily delete this question. But if you have a specific problem in the process of setting up HTTPS in your environment, then feel free to post a more specific question.

Comment: thank you Greg! i changed the title.